# Finding a Way to Describe the Infinitely Many Solutions of Tangent of an Angle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The question is as follows:

> The equation $\tan\theta = 0.9004$ has infinitely many solutions. Find a way of describing all these values of $\theta$.

How is it possible to describe those infinite solutions generally? Please explain so that an Alg II/Trig student in high school can understand it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Using a variable. For example, $\{2n : n \in \mathbb  N\}$ represents the even numbers generally, so you need to find a pattern in the solutions and use a variable like what has been done above.

Comment: You are supposed to give the "general solution" of this equation. This is a standard topic in elementary trigonometry chapters.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Thank you for responding! I am not able to understand $\{2n : n \in \mathbb  N\}$, therefore, can you please explain it a bit simpler, if you can, so that I am able to understand it.

Comment: Look at a graph of $y = \tan(x)$. See how it repeats itself over and over?  Now look for what values of $x$ we have $y = 0$.  You'll notice that they're evenly spaced (by how much?). It turns out, if we choose any real number $y$, all the values $x$ for which $\tan(x) = y$ are evenly spaced by that same amount. In other words, the entire graph can be made by translating one of the connected "pieces" of the graph to the right/left by increments of that same amount. At any rate, try writing down the $5$ closest-to-zero values $x$ for which $\tan(x) = 0$ and I'm sure you'll see a pattern emerge.

Comment: $\bf N$ is the symbol for the natural numbers. $\in$ is the symbol for "is an element of". The braces, $\{\dots\}$, stand for "the set of". So $\{\,2n:n\in{\bf N\,\}}$ means the set of all numbers of the form, twice a natural number. In other words, the even numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\tan \theta = k$, the general solution will be $$\theta = \arctan k + \begin {cases} 180n & \text {$k$ in degrees, $$n$ \in \mathbb {N}$} \\  \pi n & \text {$k$ in radians, $$n$ \in \mathbb {N}$} \end {cases}$$